# haskell Own version of Elem function using Foldl

Tags: haskell

I'm trying to create my own version of `elem` function, which returns `True` or `False` based on if the element x is inside the given array.

```
elem' :: Eq(t)=>t->[t]->Bool
elem' x xs = or [foldl (\acc -> \a -> if a == x then True else False) [] xs]
```

What I'm trying to do here is to fill the array using foldl with True/False values and then make `or` function, which returns True if at least one of them is True (so what I want to get). However, this code results in the following compilation error:

```
main.hs:11:71: error:
    * Couldn't match expected type `Bool' with actual type `[a0]'
    * In the second argument of `foldl', namely `[]'
      In the expression:
        foldl (\ acc -> \ a -> if a == x then True else False) [] xs
      In the first argument of `or', namely
        `[foldl (\ acc -> \ a -> ...) [] xs]'
   |
11 | elem' x xs = or [foldl (\acc -> \a -> if a == x then True else False) [] xs]
   |            

                                                       ^^
```

Comment: You should not use `else False`, in the case `a == x` fails, you should return the accumulator.

Comment: If you use a fold, then there's no need to employ this `or [whaterver]` approach.

Comment: Whenever you write `if expr then True else False` consider using `if (if expr then True else False) then True else False`, and then apply this advice to what you have written.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The idea of using a `foldl` is *not* to make a list of elements, and thus *not* to use `or`.

If you make use of `foldl`, then in case `a == x` fails, you look if the `elem` on the previous elements was succesful, so we return `acc` in that case. Furthermore you can not use `[]` as the "start value" for the accumulator, since the `foldl` is supposed to return a `Bool`, not a list:

```
elem' :: (Foldable f, Eq t) => t -> f t -> Bool
elem' x xs = foldl (\acc a -> if a == x then True else acc) False xs
```

Here it is however *not* a good idea to use `foldl`, since that means we will enumerate over the entire list. If we make use of `foldr`, we can stop from the moment we have found an element, so we can rewrite this to:

```
elem' :: (Foldable f, Eq t) => t -> f t -> Bool
elem' x = foldr (\e -> if x == e then const True else id) False
```

If we thus check:

```
elem' 1 ([1,4,2,5] ++ repeat 3)
```

It will return `True` for the `foldr` approach, whereas it will loop for the `foldl` approach.